# Simultaneous congruence with a coefficient for x

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Im trying to solve the following Simultaneous congruence.
$2x ≡ 3(mod\ 5) $ 
$3x ≡ 2(mod\ 4)$ 
$4x ≡ 3(mod\ 9) $

by Chinese remainder theorem 
$x$ = $B_1c_1x_1 \ + \ B_2c_2x_2 \ + B_3c_3x_3 \  $ 
Where 
$c_1 = 3$
 
$c_2 = 2 $
$c_3 = 3$
 
$B_1 = 2$x$3 $ 
$B_2 = 3$x$3 $
$B_3 = 3$x$2 $
$x_n=b_n(mod \ b_1)$
$x_1 = 1$
 
$x_2 = 1 $
$x_3 = no \ solution $

 
This is all i know and this is when $ x = c (mod \ n)$ 
but since there is a coefficient infront of x what should i change? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All coefficients in front of $x$ are coprime to their respective moduli, which means we can multiply by the inverses of said coefficients. Take the first equation:
$$2x\equiv3\bmod5$$
The multiplicative inverse of 2 modulo 5 is 3. Thus
$$x\equiv2x\cdot3\equiv3\cdot3\equiv4\bmod5$$
Similarly
$$x\equiv2\bmod4$$
$$x\equiv3\bmod9$$
Now the Chinese remainder theorem applies, and we get $x\equiv174\bmod180$.

Comment: Can you help me understand $x≡2x⋅3≡3⋅3≡4mod5$ i dont understand that part.

Comment: @ShehanTearz He multiplied the congruence $\,\color{#c00}2x\equiv 3\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}2^{-1}\equiv 3\pmod{\!5}\,$ to cancel the coefficient $\,\color{#c00}2.\,$ $\quad$

Comment: @BillDubuque so when considering the second equation $3x≡2(mod \ 4)$ we multiply it by $3^{-1}$?

Comment: @ShehanTearz Right, and $\,3\equiv -1\,$ so $\,1/3 \equiv 1/(-1)\equiv -1\ \pmod{4},\ $ so you multiply the congruence by $-1,\,$ i.e. negate it.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks